# Upload any file type to Mediawiki

Tags: mime-types, mediawiki

I've set up a MediaWiki page and now I'm trying to upload files beside images to it.
**LocalSettings.php:**

```
$wgEnableUploads = true;
$wgCheckFileExtensions = false;
$wgStrictFileExtensions = false;
```

I get this error: *File extension ".vssettings" does not match the detected MIME type of the file (application/xml).*
How can I upload this file anyway? I want users with admin rights to be able to upload any file type.

I found no solution in [the documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aConfiguring_file_uploads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to set `$wgVerifyMimeType` to false, to bypass the [mime type](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgMimeTypeBlacklist) check. As noted in the docs, you do not want to do this on a public wiki.